# Accessing Google AppEngine Cloud Endpoints using ActionScript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Is anyone aware of method of accessing Google AppEngine Cloud Enpoints using ActionScript 3 without having to go through the JavaScript layer? I have been going on the docs and Google to find any tutorials or examples but did not find anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have AS3 client libraries and currently there are none planned that I know of, so you'll have to rely on HTTP to make your REST calls.

## TLDR; Use the APIs Explorer

If you visit

```
https://your-app-id.appspot.com/_ah/api/explorer
```

(replacing `your-app-id` with your actual application ID), then you'll be redirected to your own custom version of the Google APIs Explorer.

In it you can click on individual APIs and see the list of all available methods. Within a the page for each method, you can try out forming requests and the Explorer will suggest the correct values to use.

After you click "Execute", the full HTTP request (headers and all) and response will be printed on your page, which will show you which commands to use.

## Description of how to use the Discovery Document

The Discovery Document for your API will contain all the information you need to construct a request.

To find the root for calling your API, check out the `baseUrl` key. It should be something like:

```
https://your-app-id.appspot.com/_ah/api/tictactoe/v1/
```

To figure out how to call a specific method, there are descriptions of every method, nested down as resources in the Discovery Document. For example, for the Tic Tac Toe [Python sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-endpoints-tictactoe-python), the `board_get_move` method has a `name` of `board.getmove` in the `@endpoints.api` decorator. This means the method `getmove` is owned by the resource `board`.

If you look in the `resources.board.methods` key in the Discovery Document you can see the `getmove` method:

```
"getmove": {
 "id": "tictactoe.board.getmove",
 "path": "board",
 "httpMethod": "POST",
 "description": "Exposes...",
 "request": {
  "$ref": "TictactoeApiMessagesBoardMessage"
 },
 "response": {
  "$ref": "TictactoeApiMessagesBoardMessage"
 }
}
```

Combining the `path` with our `baseUrl` we know requests will need to be sent to

```
https://your-app-id.appspot.com/_ah/api/tictactoe/v1/board
```

and from `httpMethod` we know requests will use the HTTP method `POST`.

Finally, to specify the request, we see a reference to a schema:

```
"$ref": "TictactoeApiMessagesBoardMessage"
```

Looking in the `schemas.TictactoeApiMessagesBoardMessage` key in the Discovery Document we see:

```
"TictactoeApiMessagesBoardMessage": {
 "id": "TictactoeApiMessagesBoardMessage",
 "type": "object",
 "description": "ProtoRPC message definition to represent a board.",
 "properties": {
  "state": {
   "type": "string"
  }
 }
}
```

so we know the payload must contain a single field called `state` and that field must be a string.